How to turn off undesired GCC note output for 'conflicts with register'?
I'm using an assembly registers to store pointers in my game. The register holds a different value on different threads and it all works fine, but GCC is giving me tons of notes about this:
note: conflicts with 'gDisplayListHead' register Gfx *restrict gDisplayListHead asm("$fp");

note: conflicts with 'gCurrentObject' register struct Object *gCurrentObject asm("$fp");

What is the most convenient way to get rid of that output? (without affecting the performance of my program)
I've tried finding flags to turn it off in GCC's documentation and using #pragma GCC system_header with no luck.
Compiler flags:

WARNING_FLAGS:= -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-overflow
-Wno-stringop-overflow -Winline -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-pointer-compare -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types -Wduplicated-branches -Wsuggest-attribute=const -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=cold -Wsuggest-attribute=malloc -Wsuggest-attribute=pure -Wdouble-promotion -Wimplicit-int -Wno-shift-count-overflow -Wswitch-unreachable -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wunused -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-function -Wunused-parameter -Wno-unused-result -Wunused-variable -Wunused-const-variable=2 -Wunused-value -Wunknown-pragmas -Wno-aggressive-loop-optimizations -Wno-stringop-overread
OPT_FLAGS_SIZE:= $(WARNING_FLAGS) -Os -fsingle-precision-constant
--param max-completely-peeled-insns=4 -fno-unroll-loops -finline-functions-called-once -falign-functions=0 -fmerge-all-constants -fmodulo-sched -fmodulo-sched-allow-regmoves -fira-hoist-pressure  -fipa-pta  -floop-interchange -fsplit-paths  -fallow-store-data-races -ffast-math -mframe-header-opt -nostdinc -I include/libc -DTARGET_N64 -D_LANGUAGE_C -mdivide-breaks
-mno-check-zero-division -march=vr4300  -mabi=eabi -mgp32 -mfp32 -mno-shared -mhard-float -fno-stack-protector -fno-common -mno-fix4300 -I include -I src/ -I $(BUILD_DIR)/include -fno-PIC -mno-abicalls  -ffreestanding -fwrapv -mips3


The output is:
"note: conflicts with 'gDisplayListHead'
register Gfx *restrict gDisplayListHead asm("$fp");"
This is caused by this line:
"register struct Object *gCurrentObject asm("$fp");"
I don't think this is UB - but if it is UB, a way to avoid that would be great too.

I have made the desired edits.

Thanks. Can you share the code that causes the error and GCC compiler flags you're using? Probably instead of stifling the errors and looking for a "convenient" way to "get rid" of the output, you should fix  the underlying cause. GCC warnings are usually good, possibly indicating UB that may be happening even if it seems to work.

The note appears even with all warnings turned off. Unfortunately my compiler and warning flags are longer than the character limit on this website, so I am unable to share it directly (but here is a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/AfdLh441 )
The error appears whenever the file with the line from the head issue is included. I don't think there is UB going on here - the code is pretty straightforward and just asks the compiler to use the register as though it had the variable in it.

you need to make a [mcve] and include the code itself in the question itself, not in external links which may rot anytime, and it's already inaccessible right now. See also http://www.sscce.org/

You need an n64 machine and a code with multiple threads to do a test of this setup. This is a bit of an unreasonable request.

@KazeEmanuar Next time, please add the details that others ask in the question itself, not pastebin or anything of the sorts since they can expire. In the meantime, I inlined them in the question. As for the "unreasonable request", you need to understand that you ask us for solutions on something we do not how is coded or what it does and work blindly to find a solution without even a sample code. It is not unreasonable at all. It's for a minimal reproducible example, not the project itself.

Thanks all of you for your very kind and helpful words, I couldn't ask for a better support. The issue has been resolved via -fcompare-debug-second
